# Fortran FORMAT, WRITE

Tags: format, fortran, formatting

I'm trying to write out a formatted list with fortran. Basically it is quite simple, it compiles, but gives out only rubbish.

My code:

```
     SUBROUTINE f_m ()
#ifdef _IMPLICITNONE
      implicit none
#else
      implicit logical (a-z)
#endif
c     ** Start of generated type statements **
      INCLUDE 'var'
      integer :: i
c     ** End of generated type statements **

      open(777,file='force.bla',Access='Append',status='unknown')
c     rewind(777)        
      do i=1,3
         write(777,431)cbname(i),rvar(15,i),rvar(14,i),rvar(15,i)
      end do
      write(777,*)"#############################"
      close(777)
430   Format(3A18)   
431   Format(3A12,f12.8,f12.8,f12.8)
      return
      end subroutine f_m
```

`cbname` being a character, and `rvar` real, both defined in `'var'`. The Subroutine is called during a FEM-Simulation and the end of each step.

The main Problem is, that the output looks like this:

[...i'm not allowed to post pictures right now so:]

the character is written correctly, the next two columns are, as far as i understand, random ascii or just some noise, the forth column is ok again. Opening the file comes with a error message claiming it is not utf8 formatted. Even some of the lines are cut in half, so that i only see the upper bit.

The real strange thing is: column 2 and 4 should be exactly the same.

Do you have any idea what is going on?

Comment: 'var' is a common block, in the documentation provided it is stated as a Matrix. 'rvar' is a pointer, i cannot access the code where it is pointed, but i can read out and calculate with the values it points me to. '#ifdef' uses the implicit none branch. 
Yes, it is indeed so malformated that i cannot copy it as text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

D'ohhh

The answer is obvious now.  Your format statement

```
431   Format(3A12,f12.8,f12.8,f12.8)
```

provides for 3 12-character fields followed by 3 f-p fields but your write statement

```
     write(777,431)cbname(i),rvar(15,i),rvar(14,i),rvar(15,i)
```

only provides 1 character variable, then 3 f-p variables.  The first two of these are being written under the `A12` edit descriptor, of course they look like junk.  Change statement 431 to

```
431   Format(A12,f12.8,f12.8,f12.8)
```

and see what happens

Comment: Oh god.. i feel quite embarrassed.

Thanks a lot.